# Is this double integral always positive on nonzero continuous functions?

Tags: analysis

Is this double integral
$$(f,g)=\int_{x=0}^1\int_{y=0}^1\frac{f(x)g(y)}{|y-x|^{\frac14}}dydx$$
an inner product on continuous functions on $[0,1]$? Namely, is $(f,f)$ always positive for all nonzero continuous functions $f$?

I don't know if this is true, but I conjecture it being correct.

Comment: At $(f,f)$ you just get $\int_{x=0}^1\int_{y=0}^1\frac{f^2(x)}{|y-x|^{\frac14}}dydx$ which is strictly positive, being the integral of a strictly positive function. Is this what you are asking about?

Comment: @user10444 No, you get $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{f(x) f(y)}{|y-x|^{1/4}} dy dx $.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{f(x) \overline{g(y)}}{|x-y|^{1/4}} \, dy dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat f(\xi) \overline{\hat g(\xi)} k(\xi) \, d\xi ,$$
where $k(\xi)$ is the Fourier transform of $x\mapsto |x|^{-1/4}$, that is, $k(\xi) = C |\xi|^{-3/4}$ for some constant $C > 0$.  So the answer is "yes."

Comment: Does this map to $[0,1]$?

Comment: @robjohn Yes.  Just replace $f(x)$ by $f(x) I_{x\in[0,1]}$, and ditto for $g$.

Comment: Doh! I don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: Wow that works out nicely! Thank you!